# Onclick event for presearching a user at cometchat userlist

Tags: button, vuejs2, axios, onclick, cometchat

Can someone teach me how to access CometChatUserListWithMessages from a button that redirects into my message page which I imported the cometchat. (The cometchat behaves like a widget inside my page.)

I tried the onClick event before which redirected me into Message page but cannot figure out a way to get inside cometchat’s userlist where it has the searchbar I want to prepopulate/presearch.

Here's my Card code: Here I have my Connect button which I want to redirect to my Message page.

```html
<template>
  <div class="card-container">
    <v-card variant="outlined" elevation="12" style="border-radius: 20px">
      <v-row>
        <v-col class="ml-6 mt-6">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>{{ tutor.first_name }} {{ tutor.last_name }}</h3>
          </div>
        </v-col>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <a :href="'/messages?' + tutor.first_name + tutor.last_name">
          <v-btn class="button primary mt-5">Connect</v-btn>
        </a>
      </v-row>
      <div class="ml-6">
        <p class="card-body">Program: {{ tutor.program }}</p>
        <p class="card-body">Year: {{ tutor.year }}</p>
        <p class="card-body">Subject: {{ tutor.subject }}</p>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name: "TutorCard",
      props: {
        tutor: {
          type: Object,
        },
      },
      methods: {
        connectWithTutor() {
          const query = { tutor: this.tutor.first_name + this.tutor.last_name };
          this.$router.push({ name: "messages", query });
        },
      },
    };
</script>
```

And here's my Message page: Here I have imported CometChat and cannot find a way to presearch CometChatUserList' searchbar with my Tutor name to find them and start a conversation. (Tutor name is the user's uID)

```html
<template>
  <div :class="computedClass" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh">
    <CometChatUI />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { CometChatUI } from "../../cometchat-pro-vue-ui-kit-master/CometChatWorkspace/src";
    export default {
      components: {
        CometChatUI,
      },
      computed: {
        computedClass() {
          if (this.isLargeScreen) {
            return "mt-n16";
          } else {
            return "";
          }
        },
        isLargeScreen() {
          return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp;
        },
      },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need to see your code, even if it's not working, so others can help debug and offer specific advice on how to fix your problem.  Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Following it's advice will greatly increase your chances of receiving a satisfactory answer.